# Best way to regenerate JWT in multipages app

Tags: reactjs, jwt

Let's say I authenticate users by JWT whose expiry time is in 25 minutes from creation. I create (and give the order to regenerate) the JWTs on LogIn.js file and, after login and JWT creation, the user is taken to file LandingPage.js. And later on the user might want to visit the page rendered by file Example1.js or Example2.js.

But what is the best way to keep regenerating the JWTs across the different pages/files? For instance, if I have a function on LogIn.js that keeps regenerating them even on LandingPage.js, it works until the user refreshes the page of LandingPage.js. And then the JWT is not regenerated anymore...

Thanks in advance! Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

The JWTs are generated on the server-side, not on the client-side. But before the JWT gets expired on the client, there is a function that calls the server to create a new JWT and store it on the client again. This function is the above mentioned one stored on LogIn.js

Comment: It's a bit hard to figure out how these things play toegher; because you mention react and a client should typically not generate JWTs

Comment: You're right, just added an EDIT on the question to explain that JWTs are created on the server but requested on the client by the above mentioned function